# Can I disable e-mail notification sounds streamed to a bluetooth hands-free car radio

Tags: email, bluetooth, notifications, bluetooth-hsp

**Is there a way that one can automatically turn off the email notification when one is connected to a bluetooth-enabled car radio, ie. while driving, and only respond to incoming call notifications?** Once the bluetooth connection is broken, the suppressed e-mail notifications should then be delivered.

Alternatively, if the e-mail notification is sounded, the phone should not maintain a bluetooth streaming mode status to the hands-free kit and the radio should revert to whichever audio/radio mode was previously in use.

The phone is from the Samsung Galaxy range.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Next to Location and Time, Tasker can also act on certain system events. I use this e.g. to "switch to night mode" when I place my Droid2 onto its docking station, turning it (amongst others) into "silent" mode. Similarly, you can have it react on "Bluetooth connected", and have all volumes adjusted to your convenience -- e.g. notification volume to 0, but media volume to 6 (for some music). Many more possibilities wait there...